# Reinitialise Cloud Functions from scratch

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

After having the same issue as the OP in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts), I was advised by a Google Billing Support Agent to delete the buckets created by the CloudBuild process initiated by the deployment of my Firebase Functions.

However, I now receive the following error when I attempt a deployment (function names changed):

```
⚠  functions[function1(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: could not resolve storage source: googleapi: Error 404: Not Found, notFound
⚠  functions[function2(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: could not resolve storage source: googleapi: Error 404: Not Found, notFound
⚠  functions[function3(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
```

I don't know the name of the original bucket so am unable to recreate it. I've tried reaching out to support again but they won't help as it's no longer a billing issue.

Is there a way I can get Functions to recreate the bucket so I can resume deployments?

Comment: This should still be addressed by Firebase support, as it's a new issue unrelated to billing.  I would file a new bug report and point out to them that the error message is unhelpful for diagnosing and resolving the issue.  If they don't know how to resolve the problem, they should escalate to engineering to investigate and advise.

Comment: Unfortunately Firebase support only provide billing support for free, technical support is a paid service.

Comment: That's not really true - you can certainly file bug reports.  The [form](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) provides a way to do so.  The issue here is that the message is unhelpful and there is no documentation to address this scenario.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was unaware of that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Oru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3216207/oru) stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65300654/2415238), it was necessary to recreate a bucket for the functions with a name following the pattern: `gcf-sources-<PROJECT_NUMBER>-<REGION>`.

In the case of ***Firebase*** Functions as mine was, it should be multiregion when prompted, and the `<REGION>` should be the same as shown in your error messages (`us-central1` in my case).